# CodeMirror going into infinite loop when implementing on change function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codemirror

I need to track change in CodeMirror editor. So I implemented:

```
CodeMirrorInstance.on("change", function(CodeMirrorInstance){
        $scope.onChangeFunc(CodeMirrorInstance);
    }  );
```

In `onChangeFunc` I do insert based on condition new value using

`CodeMirrorInstance.setValue(newCode);`

Apparently it leads to infinite loop. How to break this vicious circle?

Comment: You can try changeObject which is a second parameter in change event. It has five properties through which you can break the call. 
http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html

Answer (score 4):

`setValue` will always trigger another `"change"` event (it changes the content, after all). You'll have to make your change handler clever enough to not cause additional changes for changes you yourself caused. Looking at the `origin` property of the second argument passed to the `"change"` event handler might work -- it contains a sting that identifies the source of the change, which will be `"setValue"` when `setValue` was called.